# mongoose.model.find(callback) - How does it work?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, model, callback, find

I have been searching this, but could not understand. I have an app on node.js to access the MongoDB data using mongoose.

```
//contents of book.js
var Book = module.exports = mongoose.model('Books',genreSchema)
Book.getBooks = function(call,limit){
               Book.find(call).limit(limit);
               console.log(call.toString());
               }


//contents of app.js
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bookstore');
var db = mongoose.connection;    
Books = require('./models/book');
app.get('/api/book', function(req,res){
        Books.getBooks(function(err, book){ 
                  if(err){ throw err;}
                          res.json(book);
                    });
        });
```

The `call.toString()` returns the callback function definition in app.js. How does the `Book.find(call)` queries internally to match the collection name (though I don't explicitly specify the collection name) to fetch the records incorrectly?

I pass a definition to `find()` with absolutely no reference to what is to be fetched from DB except the db connection used.

I want to know how does this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define the `Book` model using:

```
var Book = module.exports = mongoose.model('Books', genreSchema)
```

Mongoose takes the lower-cased and pluralized model name of `'Books'` to get the collection name of `books`.

You can explicitly define the collection name to use via the optional third parameter to `model`:

```
var Book = module.exports = mongoose.model('Books', genreSchema, 'books')
```